# Problem with gmock SetArgPointee<> pass pointer

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

When trying to pass a pointer to a SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS on gmock the error " C2440 "=": "const A" cannot be converted to "BYTE" Service_Test c-actions.h 915" is displayed.

Gtest

```
EXPECT_CALL(*foo, do(_)).WillOnce(Return());
testservice->execute();

SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssp;
ssp.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
EXPECT_CALL(*iqueryservicestatus, QueryServiceStatusEx, (_, _, _,_,_)).WillOnce(DoAll(::testing::SetArgPointee<2>( (LPBYTE)&ssp),Return(TRUE)));

EXPECT_EQ(testservice->stop("Service"), 0L);
```

gmock

```
class MockQueryServiceStatus : public QueryServiceStatus
{

public:
MOCK_METHOD(BOOL, QueryServiceStatusEx, (SC_HANDLE  hServic, SC_STATUS_TYPE InfoLevel, LPBYTE lpBuffer, DWORD cbBufSize, LPDWORD pcBbytesNeeded), (override));

};
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with SetArgPointee, but I think you want to set the value of the thing pointed-to. Have you tried simply removing `(LPBYTE)&` and just passing `ssp`?

Comment: Yes i have tried removing (LPBYTE)& and just passing ssp, it don't works